# How to code a script that clears (all) the content of a desired sheet (whose name is specified in a cell of another sheet)?

Tags: javascript, excel, function, google-sheets, formula

Basically, I am trying to do what the following function does: Clear a specified range of content in a specified sheet

`function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A1:Z1000').clearContent();
}`

However, I am trying to modify this function:
- to avoid the hardcode of the name of the sheet I want to clear, but instead, simply input it in a cell.

In my spreadsheet, I have 3 different sheets: namely "settings_sheet", "sheet1" and "sheet2".

Here are my specifications:

1) In the "settings_sheet", I want to be able to write in the cell B3 the name of the sheet I want to clear, either "sheet1" or "sheet2" (without the quotes).

2) Thanks to a UI button (insert-->drawings) in the "settings_sheet", associated to the script, I want to clear by a simple click the sheet which name is specified in B3

Here is the script I tried to develop, without success so far:

```
function clearSelectedSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet ID");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('settings_sheet'); 
var range = sheet.getRange('B3'); 
var data = range.getValue();

if(data == "sheet1"){
var templatename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
templatename.getRange('A1:Z1000').clearContent();
} 

if(data == "sheet2"){
var templatename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet2');
templatename.getRange('A1:Z1000').clearContent();
}}
```

I know how to integrate the UI button. Thanks by advance for any help to develop a functional script!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function clearSelectedSheet() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('settings_sheet'); 
var range = sheet.getRange('B3'); 
var data = range.getValue();

var templatename = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(data);
templatename.getRange('A1:Z1000').clearContent();
}
```